# Java: replaceAll doesn't work as I think it should

Tags: java, replaceall

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String piece = "10*2";
            String ans = "20";
            String problm = "10*2*9";

            System.out.println(piece);
            System.out.println(ans);

            problm.replaceAll(piece, ans);

            System.out.println(problm);
    }
}
```

This is my code, and when  I print `problm` it prints: `10*2*9`
I want it to print `20*9`, please tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: The first `replaceAll` parameter should be a regular-expression.  So, in this case it is recognizing the `*`.  Use the slash `\ ` to escape those characters.  `problm = "10\\*2\\*9"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`. `replaceAll` uses regular expressions, which you probably don't want.

Secondly, Strings in Java are *immutable*, meaning that their value can never be changed. You need to assign the value of `problm.replaceAll(piece, ans);` back to `problm`:

```
problm = problm.replace(piece, ans);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate problems here:

1. `replaceAll` works with regular expressions. If you don't understand regular expressions yet, you probably want `replace` instead.
2. You're ignoring the result of `replaceAll`, and printing the original string. You should print the result instead:

   ```
   String solution = problm.replace(piece, ans);
   System.out.println(solution);
   ```

   (Of course, you don't have to use a temporary variable, and you don't have to call it `solution` if you do)

Comment: Instead of creating a new variable I just used the same variable problm so: problm = problm.replace(piece, ans); and then print problm. Save my day thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign that to problm again. A String is immutable and can not be changed.